# Google analytics grossly under-reports number of clicks to a site

Tags: google-analytics

According to Clicky Analytics, the site http://www.houseofwords.com, specifically the page http://www.houseofwords.com/other/sight-gags.html, got 162 clicks/visits on Feb. 9. Ave time spent there was 24 sec, giving a (clicky) bounce rate of 77%. Certainly not great.
Google Analytics says it was 2 clicks. Most visits were from reddit.com. I had just posted a link to http://www.houseofwords.com/other/sight-gags.html on reddit. That's why the traffic. There's nothing wrong with Clicky. The problem is Google Analytics (using "new" Search Console.) The same scenario has played out many times.

```
ga snippet (in header) -----------
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new 
Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-
analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-82097736-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>

Clicky snippet (just before </body> ) - Just for reference -------------
<script src="//static.getclicky.com/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{ clicky.init(101008026); }catch(e){}
</script>
<noscript><p><img alt="Clicky" width="1" height="1" 
src="//in.getclicky.com/101008026ns.gif" /></p></noscript>
```

Neither script has an onClick, never-the-less, Clicky script words.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Are you sure what are you lloking? Clicks on Google Analytics? Sessions? Pageview? Seems that are you comparing sessions with ageview, also not sure if you have in consideration about the Robot Exlusion check on the view

Comment: My question is, why is ga under-reporting daily number of clicks?

Comment: Do you have an answer?